# Entropy: Is $H(X_{1},X_{2}) = H(X_{1})$ true?

Tags: information-theory

**Question:**
If $X_{1}, X_{2}$ are two discrete random variables. $X_{1}, X_{2}$ have the same probability distribution can we then deduce that:

> $H(X_{1}, X_{2}) = H(X_{1})$

is true?

**Remark:** $H(X)$ denotes the entropy of the random variable $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, we can not.

$H(X_1,X_2)=H(X_1)+H(X_2|X_1)$, but if $X_1,X_2$ are independent and $H(X_1)>0$ then

$H(X_2|X_1)=H(X_2)=H(X_1)>0$

Hence $H(X_1,X_2)=H(X_1)+H(X_2)=2H(X_1)>H(X_1)$.

Therefore $H(X_1,X_2)=H(X_1)$ is not valid.

Comment: You are welcome.